# Angular 2+ display array item in html

Tags: angular

I recently started learning angular and wanted to create a slider.

I created an array of objects which will hold data for the sliders images and tried to display them in my components html file like this:

Ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    type sliderImgMeta = Array<{id:number,src:string,alt:string}>;

    const arr: sliderImgMeta = [
      {id: 1, src: './img/slider1', alt: 'alt1'},
      {id: 2, src: './img/slider2', alt: 'alt2'},
      {id: 3, src: './img/slider3', alt: 'alt3'}
    ]
  }

}
```

And the html file:

```
<section id="slider">
  <div id="slider-content">
    <img src="{{arr[0].src}}" alt="{{arr[0].alt}}">
  </div>
  <div id="slider-navigation">
    <span id="moveLeft"><</span>
    <span id="moveRight">></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

In return im getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and unfortunetly have no idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you haven't `arr` property in your class, instead you created variable in `ngOnInit` which is accessible only inside it, try this way and note also that  `sliderImgMeta` type should be outside of class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

type sliderImgMeta = Array<{id:number,src:string,alt:string}>;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-slider',
  templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
})
export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {
  arr: sliderImgMeta = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.arr = [
      {id: 1, src: './img/slider1', alt: 'alt1'},
      {id: 2, src: './img/slider2', alt: 'alt2'},
      {id: 3, src: './img/slider3', alt: 'alt3'}
    ]
  }

}
```

Comment: That solved the issue thanks for the explanation as well :) will mark as solved in a few minutes

Comment: @aMJay ok glad to help !!

Comment: This solution works. But, it will throw error once. Because when view is ready, property isnt defined yet. If you want see this error, you can add ngIf to view.@aMJay

Comment: @EmircanOk it will not throw error because `ngOnInit` triggers before view init, so when view will start init `arr` property will be ready

Answer (score 0):

You define property in class for access from view.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-slider',
      templateUrl: './slider.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./slider.component.scss']
    })

    type sliderImgMeta = Array<{id:number,src:string,alt:string}>;    

    export class SliderComponent implements OnInit {

      arr: sliderImgMeta = [
          {id: 1, src: './img/slider1', alt: 'alt1'},
          {id: 2, src: './img/slider2', alt: 'alt2'},
          {id: 3, src: './img/slider3', alt: 'alt3'}
        ];

      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {

      }

    }
```